# On ADO.NET entity framework, the DbContext object does not have a table field

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework

I am using VS 2015 Community, Windows 10, Microsoft SQL 2016 SP1.
I added an SQL Server DB to the project. Then I added a table named 'Dict' to that database.[image: database pictured here]

I am following [this tutorial (at 20:00)](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Programming-in-C-Jump-Start/Programming-in-C-08-Using-LINQ-to-Objects-and-XML-and-Serialization#time=20m00s) which explains how to use ADO.NET with Visual Studio. The video is a bit outdated, but I followed the same steps to create the entity model. But when I get to the part in 21:01, my DbContext object (seen below) returns an error when I try to access context.Dict. It says no definition found for Dict.

```
    public partial class _Default : Page
      {
         protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
            var context = new DictServerEntities1();

            var words = context.Dict;
```

UPDATE:

I imported some sample databases provided by Microsoft (called Northwind), and they work with EF. So my table is somehow not valid for EF, I'm guessing because it does not contain a primary key.

Comment: Just found out that  SQL Server Compact is no longer used on VS 2015, so that video is outdated. Apparenly LocalDB is used now. Deleting the question about creating a local database.

Comment: Do you see Dict in your .edmx model? Is it possible that you did not check the table you want to generate as explained in 18:13?

Comment: No, but I did check the table.

Comment: I don't have VS2015 but upon saving the .edmx it should generate the model and the code  (see 18:54). For me it worked right away in VS2017. Maybe you generated the model before creating the table since the context is generated. Does the message "Running this text template can potentially harm your computer..." appear and is the script executed? Check the VS Output window for details after you hit OK.

Comment: I remember that text template window appearing, but I always had the table before the model. The output says that 'Could not save the XML to the configuration file Web.config' because another process is using it...

Comment: I tried importing a sample database project to see if the EF would work with them. It does, so I think the problem is with the way my Dict database table is set up. Something about the table is not allowing it to be converted into an Entity Model by default (the model class is not being created when I add new ADO EF and choose Dict as the table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this was to use a table with a primary key. I was not using a primary key.